# iOS Facebook login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login

I would to add Facebook login into my iOS app..
I have read the Facebook documentation and tutorial about Facebook 3.0 iOS framework..but

I see that when this call is invoked:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:
                     permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI 
                     completionHandler:
                               ^(FBSession *session,
                                 FBSessionState state,
                                 NSError *error) {

                                             //...mycode
                                }];
```

the control passes out of my app to facebook to insert credentials and then come back into my app when the user has entered his data.
You can do this by entering their credentials directly in the app?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think this is possible. It would actually mean that apps would get user login information which is definitely not what most users want.